# Stop floated elements pushing right

Tags: css

just a quick question...

I will first show you the problem I am having in a video for better understanding:

http://screencast.com/t/pFKCOrkOJ

As you can see when I add words with more characters to my floated elements they push to the right causing the lists to be out of line with each other.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="ul-listing-container">
            <ul>
              <li class="diesel-svg">Diesel</li>
              <li class="saloon-svg">Saloon</li>
              <li class="gear-svg">Automatic</li>
              <li class="color-svg">Orange</li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.diesel-svg {
    list-style-type: none;
    background:url(/../media/img/nozzle.svg);
    background-size: 45px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left:50px;
    float:left;
    color:#eee;
    font: 400 1.2em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
    background-position: 0px 7px;
    text-align: center;
}

.saloon-svg {
    list-style-type: none;
    background:url(/../media/img/saloon.svg);
    background-size: 45px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left:50px;
    float:left;
    color:#eee;
    bottom:5px;
    font: 400 1.2em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 1em;
    background-position: 0px 7px;
    text-align: center;
}

.gear-svg {
    list-style-type: none;
    background:url(/../media/img/gears.svg);
    background-size: 45px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left:50px;
    float:left;
    color:#eee;
    bottom:5px;
    font: 400 1.2em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
    background-position: 0px 7px;
    text-align: center;
}

.color-svg {
    list-style-type: none;
    background:url(/../media/img/color.svg);
    background-size: 45px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left:50px;
    float:left;
    color:#eee;
    bottom:5px;
    font: 400 1.2em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 1em;
    background-position: 0px 7px;
    text-align: center;
}


.ul-listing-container {
    width:39%;
    float:left;
    margin:auto;
}
```

This will become a listing page so I need to be prepared for many value changes to the elements.

I want the elements to push out to the right and left as more characters are added instad of the right only and also to perform this to the li's below that so those aren't out of line also.

Any idea how I could do this?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note, you seem to be repeating a lot of CSS rules. You should make one class `list-svg` that you use for all those list elements, then an id for each individual element to apply unique rules.

Comment: Thanks I thought it seemed like a lot of CSS :)

Comment: Alternatively, if you ever need them to have different rules, use: `.gear-svg, .color-svg .saloon-svg, .diesel-svg {}`.  This will use the rules for 4 classes, then you can style each one seperately if needed also.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a specific width. In the elements that are right of the picture you can move them all over just a bit more and gauge what your LONGEST possible string could be. If Automatic is the longest string then just gauge off that width. And then set all LIs to that width. Then do the css so that the LIs fit as you wish them to.

The strings change width when they are longer as they should. There isn't much else. If you put too small of a width then the words could end up overlapping. You should utilize the space next to the image as that is nearly 20-30px.

Also what @Aleatoric said use a class to apply to all of these that way your other pages are not affected.